# Haskell Guard method to print the grade

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell programming, I have a requirement to print the grades based on the marks using Guard. Please find below code.

Any help would be appreciate as I am getting compiler error.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> String’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "MediumPass"
      In an equation for ‘printMarks’:
          printMarks mark
            | mark >= 50 && mark <= 59 = "MediumPass"
            | mark >= 60 && mark <= 69 = "High Pass"
            | mark >= 80 && mark <= 100 = "Distinction"
            | otherwise = error "invalid mark"
```

The code:

```
printMarks :: Integer -> Integer -> String

printMarks mark | mark >= 50 && mark <= 59 = "MediumPass"
                | mark >= 60 && mark <= 69 = "High Pass"
                | mark >= 80 && mark <= 100 = "Distinction"
                | otherwise = error "invalid mark" 

main = do
    putStrLn "Printing Grade"
    print(printMarks 51)
```

Comment: Strange that GHC did not provide you more helpful message (that is, your function is applied one time less). Why is your function taking 2 Integers? Is it your intention to take 2 integers, or did you accidentally added additional parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `printMarks` should be `Integer -> String` and not `Integer -> Integer -> String` because `printMarks` takes an `Integer` and produces a `String`.

```
printMarks :: Integer -> String

printMarks mark
    | mark >= 50, mark <= 59  = "MediumPass"
    | mark >= 60, mark <= 69  = "High Pass"
    | mark >= 80, mark <= 100 = "Distinction"
    | otherwise               = error "invalid mark" 

main = do
    putStrLn "Printing Grade"
    print(printMarks 51)
```

output

```
tarptaeya@Anmols-MBP Temp % runghc foo.hs 
Printing Grade
"MediumPass"
```

In Haskell `f :: a -> b -> c` means that if you call `f` with an object of type `a`, then it will return an function of type `b -> c`.